# How to pass environment variables as parameters for readProperties file in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

when using readProperties in Jenkins, How can we pass environment variables as parameters to props[ ]?

Properties file:
test.properties

Monday=abcdef

Tuesday=kfgh

Jenkins code:

```
 environment {
       Day = "Monday"   
    } 

 
    
    def props=readProperties file:"${WORKSPACE}/test.properties"
       monday_value=props['Monday'] //works
       monday_value=props[env.Day] //Doesn't work
```

Comment: I think your usage of env variable is wrong. Have you tried like this: `monday_value=props["${env.Day}"]`

Comment: It worked. Thanks!!

Comment: You welcome :) I have updated the answer. Please accept it.

Comment: Done, Accepted your Answer. Thanks Again!!

Comment: If you don't mind, could you kindly help me with this question too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042250/how-to-maintain-a-single-jenkinsfile-and-create-two-jenkins-jobs-with-different     @SouravAtta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variable in Jenkins should be invoked using `env`

So, you should try like this:

```
monday_value=props["${env.Day}"]
```