# How to maintain a single Jenkinsfile and create two jenkins jobs with different choice parameters

Tags: jenkins

I wanted to use single Jenkinsfile and create 2 pipeline jobs, one should populate DEV, IT, UAT  and other should populate PROD, DR as choices for choice parameter (ENV).

I was able to achieve this by below code and defining choices in UI:

```
[$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', name: 'ENV', choices:params.DEPLOY_ENV, description: 'Select ENV'],
```

This works if I only have one choice (DEV) defined in UI, but if I have more than one choice (DEV, IT, UAT) and if user selects 2nd choice (IT) and runs the job, it deletes the other choices for some reason and now it only shows one choice (IT) in drop down.

I can achieve this by not defining parameters in Jenkinsfile and selecting 'This Project is parameterized' in UI and using the defined parameters with 'params.' but I don't think it's the right approach for my project.

Is there a better way to use single jenkinsfile for creating two pipeline jobs with different choice parameters?

Comment: As far as I understand from your question, you can create two pipeline jobs using [Jenkins Job DSL Plugin](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/)

Comment: @SouravAtta I am sorry if my questions wasn't clear, I am looking to create two pipeline jobs with same jenkinsfile - when you select 'Build with Parameters' for first job it should have choices UAT1, UAT2 for ENV and the other job should have PROD1, PROD2 as choices for ENV.

Comment: @Sreekar How do you want the options to be chosen, according to the Job name? or according to something else?

Comment: @Sreekar Do you have pipeline jobs already for UAT and PROD environment? If yes, do you want to trigger those jobs from one upstream job ?